# Change location of navigation bar when it would overlap content

Tags: html, css, navigation

How do I get my navigation bar to not overlap onto the picture, and when it does it goes underneath it, so you are still able to read the picture and use the navigation?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/HvJc5/) is a link to my code.

CSS

```
.navigation{
list-style-type: none;
position: absolute;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.navigation ul{
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0; 
text-align: right;
float: right;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.navigation li{
display: inline;
padding-left: 10px;
vertical-align: middle;
font-size: 24px;
}

.header .navigation{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 20px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="live" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Unit 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Unit 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Unit 3</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

If the question didn't make sense, make the result window fairly large and then zoom in and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Can you take a look at this and see if this works? http://jsfiddle.net/HvJc5/4/

Comment: @BuddhistBeast That's exactly what I want except I can't seem to get the picture in the middle with the navigation being on the left, but also on the same 'line' if you know what I mean.

Comment: Hmm... try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/HvJc5/7/ if you zoom in and out, the picture will go in the middle as you zoom in and to the right as you zoom out, maintaining that inline balance.

Comment: If you could click my answer as being right, that would be great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HvJc5/8/)

It seems you had your picture floating to the left, represented by this CSS:

```
float: left;
```

which would mean that all of your content would be to the right of the photo no matter what, so I just took that line of code out, and made the picture `text-align:center;` which means the photo would stay centered no matter what (giving you that nice responsive movement).

Just do me a favor, stay away from the position effects (relative, absolute, fixed) unless you absolutely need it... floats are better to use because they respond much better than positioning effects do. Plus, absolute positioning can definitely give you a headache after a while!

Hope this helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `z-index` property

**css**

```
.header h1 a{
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    width: 135px;
    height: 50px;
    background: url(http://www.gpccolorado.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Square-head.jpg);
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index:500;
    position:relative;
}
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HvJc5/2/)

Comment: Although that's useful to know, it's not what I want as once it goes behind the picture the users are unable to use the links to navigate around.